# Squared binomial paradox?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

When you square this $$(5-2)^2$$ you will get 49 $$ 5^2 - 2 * 5 * (-2) + (-2)^2$$
$$25 + 20 + 4 = 49$$ but if you do it like this (5-2) * (5-2) you will get 9 $$ 5(5-2) - 2(5-2)$$
$$25-10-10+4$$
$$25-20+4$$
$$5+4$$
$$9$$
Why do I always get different results if I'm doing the same thing?Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: should be $2\cdot 5\cdot (-2)$ instead of $-2\cdot 5\cdot (-2)$. Man you have serious trouble.

Comment: Yes, you are doing $-2·5·(-2)$. If you use the rule $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ then you should say $+2·5·(-2)$. If you use the rule $(a-b)^2 = a^2 -2ab+b^2$ you should say $-2·5·2$

Comment: $(5-2)^2$ is not 49. It is $3^2=9$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial formular is $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$

If you apply it:

$$(5 - 2)^2 = 5^2 + 2\cdot5\cdot(-2) + 2^2 = 25-20 + 4 = 9$$

The second binomial formular is  $(a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$

If you apply it:

$$(5 - 2)^2 = 5^2 - 2\cdot5\cdot 2 + 2^2 = 25-20 + 4 = 9$$

Your mistake was, that you used the second binomial formular but took $a$ as $-2$ instead as $2$.

Comment: About second formula, you are doing it like this $$- 2 * 5 * 2$$ but isn't 2 negative (that 2 after 5), in your case minus disappeared?

Comment: No, the formular says that $-b = -2$, therefore $b = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have actually done a blunder !!

$(5-2)^2=5^2-(2\times5\times2)+(-2)^2=25-20+4=9.$

Note that $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$

Comment: But why doesn't 2nd number 2 in brackets have minus while the one after + (squared 2) has?

Comment: Because in the second term the minus sign is taken care in the beginning itself !! You can view it as $5^2+(2\times5\times(-2))+(-2)^2$ if you don't understand !!

Comment: This is what I was trying to say - $$ (a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2 * a * (-b)$$ the sign after squared 'a' (minus) is the one in brackets and another one after 2 * 5 * (-2), i am doing it without brackets because I thought that there should be 2 minuses (1 after squared a and again one after multiplying b with 2 and a), in other words I either forgot squared binomial or my teacher taught us wrong :\ we never put brackets after minus

Comment: The minus sign that you put before 2 is actually the one coming from the minus sign of b

Comment: Well yes, that is why i said that the sign after first squared digit is the one in brackets (which belongs to b) and that is why I'm asking why the 2nd number 2 (b) after multiplying with 2 doesn't have minus (this one (2×5×2) )